# Sql getting two rows from second table in one statement

Tags: mysql, sql, sql-server

I have two tables:

```
Order Table
ID OrderDate Employee Manager
1  1/1/2016 100   101
2  1/2/2016 100   101
3  1/2/2016 100
4  1/2/2016       101

Employee Table
Eid  Name
100  Matt
101  Bill
```

I need the result like this

```
1/1/2016 Matt Bill
1/2/2016 Matt Bill
1/2/2016 Matt
1/2/2016      Bill

My SQL
Select O.* from Orders
JOIN Employee E on O.Employee=E.Eid
JOIN Employee E on O.Manager=E.Eid
Where O.OrderDate > '2016-01-01'
```

I get no result. If I remove the JOIN's I get all orders and the employee and managers Eid.

Thanks for any help,
Kim

Comment: Can you amend to show the dates correctly formatted according to the data type. It's just too confusing otherwise

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your query you have not created alias for Orders table. And You should have to use left join because you have to fetch all the records from orders table and if related record exist in the employee table then only it will be fetched. Please look in to below query.

```
Select O.*, E.Name, M.Name from Orders as O
LEFT JOIN Employee E on O.Employee=E.Eid
LEFT JOIN Employee M on O.Manager=M.Eid
Where O.OrderDate > '2016-01-01'
```

Answer (score 0):

use a different alias when you join to the same table again.

```
Select O.* , E.Name, M.Name
from Orders O
JOIN Employee E on O.Employee=E.Eid
JOIN Employee M on O.Manager=M.Eid
Where O.OrderDate > '2016-01-01'
```

Comment: shouldn't it be `from Orders O`

Answer (score 0):

```
Select O.* , E.Name, M.Name
from Orders O
JOIN Employee E on O.Employee=E.Eid
JOIN Employee M on O.Manager=M.Eid
Where O.OrderDate > '2016-01-01'
```

Answer (score -1):

Try this

```
Select O.* , E.Name, M.Name
 from Orders O
 JOIN Employee E on O.Employee=E.Eid
 JOIN Employee M on O.Manager=M.Eid
 Where date( O.OrderDate)>date( '2016-01-01')
```

I have added date function , both dates will converted to MySQL date format first.

Comment: Sorry for my English. What is the output for select date(now()); it will return date. Comparing to date with date will be more secure comparing date with string. I mean like that

Comment: Sorry for any mistake

Comment: This does not work I only get the records where booth employee and manager id is present, not all records where just one of the Id is present.

Comment: Select O.OrderDate, E.Name, M.Name
 from Orders O
 LEFT JOIN Employee E on O.Employee=E.Eid
 LEFT JOIN Employee M on O.Manager=M.Eid
 Where date( O.OrderDate)>date( '2016-01-01')